# Find Thunderbird recipients with certain criteria

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'd like to basically use the email history in Thunderbird to extract addresses of people I've frequently exchanged emails with in an automated manner.

What would be the best way to find

- all recipients for emails in a Thunderbird ***Sent*** folder
- that have at least, say, 50 separate emails (over the complete life span of the Sent folder)

Would it be possible to query the Thunderbird DB for this information?
Or is there some higher level mechanism to allow this kind of analysis?